# What does each column in an archive's table of contents mean? (pg_dump/pg_restore)

Tags: postgresql

I'm using pg_restore to reconstitute a database I've backed up. As suggested in the pg_restore docs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/curren/app-pgrestore.html), I've created a .list file with the archive's table of contents.

Nothing is wrong per se, but I'm struggling to figure out what every column in this ToC means. They each look like this:

```
5602; 0 16476 TABLE DATA public <table_name> postgres
```

The first column is the archive id for that table, but what do the next two numbers mean? In my ToC the first non-archive column is always zero but in other examples that's not true.

Comment: We're on 9.5 and it isn't a decision I've made. I already read that about the first column but thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The fields pertain to:

- Archive ID
- Catalog Table OID (0 in your case, because that row pertains to `TABLE DATA` and not a table.  A proc would get the value of `SELECT oid FROM pg_class were relname = 'pg_proc'` here, a table would get `SELECT oid FROM pg_class where relname = 'pg_class'`, etc.)
- Table OID (16476 is the oid you would find in `pg_class`)
- Description (`TABLE DATA` in your example)
- Schema (`public` in your example)
- Name (`<table_name>`)
- Owner (`postgres` in your example)

Comment: Pulled it out of source https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_backup_archiver.c#L1192